# Extract values from list of lists with R

Tags: r

I have list of lists similar to this sample:

```
z <- list(list(num1=list((list(tab1=list(list(a=1, b=2, c=5), list(a=3, b=4), list(d=4,e=7)))))),list(num2=list((list(tab2=list(list(a=1, b=2), list(a=3, b=4)))))))
```

I would like to extract the figures out of the last list of lists names:

Desired output list (since 1 list entries are shorter) or as dataframe with columns corresponding to main list:

```
[1] a b c a b d e

[2] a b a b
```

dataframe:

```
column1  column2
 a         a
 b         b
 c         a 
 a         b
 b         ""
 d         "" 
 e         ""
```

I have tried various combinations of `sapply(z, "[[", c("a","b"...)` but failed, since the sublist names varies.

**EDIT:** Sorry, I needed the actual values not the last node (letters)! Additionally, each numeric value has column name, not set in the example above; it is like this:

```
[[1]]$num1[[1]]$tab1[[1]]$a
     Name
     1
```

So the desired solution are values:

```
[1] 
1 2 5 3 4 4 7 
[2]
1 2 3 4
```

I would actually need the numeric values instead of the letters. If you could adjust your solution to this I would be grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit far-fetched and everything but elegant, here is a way to get what you want :

```
lista<-unlist(lapply(strsplit(names(unlist(z)),"\\."),function(vec) vec[3]))
names(lista)<-unlist(lapply(strsplit(names(unlist(z)),"\\."),function(vec) vec[1]))
uninames<-unique(names(lista))

res<-sapply(uninames,function(x,vec){vec[names(vec)==x]},lista)

> res
$num1
num1 num1 num1 num1 num1 num1 num1 
 "a"  "b"  "c"  "a"  "b"  "d"  "e" 

$num2
num2 num2 num2 num2 
 "a"  "b"  "a"  "b"
```

**UPDATE**

To get the numbers :

```
a<-unlist(z)
b<-names(unique(z))
res<-sapply(unique(b),function(name,vec,l_name){vec[l_name==name]},a,b)

>res
$num1
num1.tab1.a num1.tab1.b num1.tab1.c num1.tab1.a num1.tab1.b num1.tab1.d num1.tab1.e 
          1           2           5           3           4           4           7 

$num2
num2.tab2.a num2.tab2.b num2.tab2.a num2.tab2.b 
          1           2           3           4
```

Comment: I would accept your answer for number of reasons. (effort & other purpose (learning)). Many thanks!

Comment: Thank you ! But of course, for the "second version" of your question, David's answer is way better...

Comment: Yes, David's answer is the way to go on this occation. His answer remains on SO, so it is matter of choice.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
lapply(z, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(x)))

## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 5 3 4 4 7
##       
## [[2]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: @DavidArenburg, just a closing bracket from the perfect answer... ;-)

Comment: NO WAY! :) it really pays off thinking in simplicity!

Answer (score 3):

```
z1 <- lapply(z, function(x) names(unlist(x)))
z1 <- lapply(z1, function(x) gsub(".*\\.", "", x))
n <- max(sapply(z1, length))
z1 <- lapply(z1, `length<-`, value = n)
setNames(as.data.frame(z1), paste0("Column", seq_along(z1)))
#  Column1 Column2
#1       a       a
#2       b       b
#3       c       a
#4       a       b
#5       b    <NA>
#6       d    <NA>
#7       e    <NA>
```